# Network configuration with 3 Oracle VirtualBox VMs

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a requirement to create 3 VMs and configure the machines as below :
two machines with their distinct networks
third machine contains above two networks that my client can communicate to both machines mentioned above.

1. Oracle VB VM1 (Windows 11 with Network1 only)
2. Oracle VB VM2 (Ubuntu 22 with Network1 and Network2)
3. Oracle VB VM3 (Ubuntu 20 with Network2 only)

I have a separate Client that can only have access to Network2.

Any ideas how can I achieve this.

Comment: Your first scenario must use Bridged Networking (VBOX setting) for outside (remote) clients to communicate with the machines.

Comment: What/Where is this separate Client? Is it also a VM?

Comment: @u1686_grawity the client has to be on VM3 and also on a different machine that has access to Network2.

Comment: So you need Bridged networking as I said.

Comment: @John Thank you, I have the first VM already bridged, which is interfacing with my Wifi network. All 3 VMs have to be bridged ?

Comment: Yes, because accessing from another machine requires a direct connection (not VBOX NAT)

Comment: Sure, I understand. But the VMs have to be on different Networks. So via bridged, we get only 1 network.

Comment: Yes. that is the way it has to work.

Comment: So just to reconfirm, VM1(Network1), VM3(Network2) can be achieved by bridging to my wifi adapter, gives different network on VM1 & VM3 ?

Comment: That depends on your WiFi router connection to your main router. Basically for a device outside to properly access, you need to keep everything on one subnet for simplicity.

Comment: Sure, I only have one modem and a router.  So, I thought I need to have two different networks (subnets), that I tried creating two NatNetworks with different ranges 10.0.2.15/24 and 10.0.3.15/24 respectively. And assigned one NatNetwork each to VM1 and VM3, so I thought I will get different networks. Problem is I can't communicate and its obvious that they are in different networks and started looking for a solution for them to communicate.

Comment: Put your subnets into 1 for simplicity. You are (in my thinking) making things difficult for yourself

Comment: I am pretty sure I am complicating maybe. So, you mean just use one subnet (NatNetwork), instead of 2 ?

Comment: Yes - just one subnet. I routinely connect to various VMs and computers around here. Simplicity wins every time.

Comment: Thank you, I will try doing that and see if it works.